# Referencing Element Of List In Terraform Templated Yaml File

Tags: terraform

I am trying to pass a map of lists to a templated yaml file and then reference a specific element of that list.  I know that this leverages the legacy `template_file` type, but I am still curious as to why what I am doing does not render.  The same logic works fine when I test it via locals.

**variable:**

```
variable "my_recipients" {
  description = "Recipients To Identify"
  type        = map(list(string))
  default = {
    abcd = [
      "myrecipientA"
    ],
    zyx = [
      "myrecipientB"
    ]
  }
}
```

**template_file snippet:**

```
data "template_file" "policies" {
  template = myfile.yaml
    recipients_all                    = jsonencode(var.my_recipients)
}
```

**yaml file snippet:**

```
to:
  - ${jsondecode({recipients_all})["zyx"]} #Goal is to get the value myrecipientB
```

I expect to get the value myrecipientB, but instead I get the error:

```
Missing key/value separator; Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value.
```

Any advice would be appreciated as this seems like a simple idea that should work, and I'm not sure what I am misunderstanding.

Comment: I think the problem you are running into has to do with some minor details on what things are expected for each function and for the template.  What do you expect to see at the end, the complete list of elements mapped to 'xyz' (["myrecipientB"]?  The first element on the list for 'xyz' ("myrecipientB")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue might be with how things are defined and passed from terraform to the template.  There seemed to be some minor syntax errors on the template itself.  Plus, the template file wants the results of the interpolation to be a string so it can be included on the rendered results.

Here's the code that worked for me.

**combined terraform code:**

```
variable "my_recipients" {
  description = "Recipients To Identify"
  type        = map(list(string))
  default = {
    abcd = [
      "myrecipientA"
    ],
    zyx = [
      "myrecipientB"
    ]
  }
}

data "template_file" "policies" {
  template = file("myfile.tpl")
  vars = {
    recipients_all                    = jsonencode(var.my_recipients)
  }
}

# For debugging purposes
locals {
    recepients_all_encoded = jsonencode(var.my_recipients)
}

output "recepients_all_encoded" {
    value = local.recepients_all_encoded
}

output "template_content" {
    value = data.template_file.policies.rendered
}
```

**updated template file (myfile.tpl)**

```
to:
  - ${jsondecode(recipients_all)["zyx"][0]}
```

**Results from terraform run**

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

recepients_all_encoded = "{\"abcd\":[\"myrecipientA\"],\"zyx\":[\"myrecipientB\"]}"
template_content = <<EOT
to:
  - myrecipientB

EOT
```